# I can't see my trees through camera but I can see everything else

Tags: camera

when you look on the left in modelling view you can see the london eye the trees and the Thames but when you look on the right through camera view you can no longer see the trees.

how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is the ray visibility for camera on?

Comment: this would only make a difference in rendered view but not in solid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a camera clipping issue. Seems like your camera simply is not set up to look this far.

Select the camera and increase the clipping end value as shown below.

For further explanation see the manual:
https://www.blender.org/manual/es/render/cycles/camera.html

It says:

"*Clipping
Clip Start and End:
The interval in which objects are directly visible, Any objects outside this range still influence the image indirectly, as further light bounces are not clipped.*"

[image]